# how to select rows based on other row in R？

Tags: r

The raw dataframe is as follow example, it include id year and other two variables-list and value. for a row's list varible equal 1, i want to retain the row have the same id but year is year+1 and year-1.

```
id  year    list    value
1   2008    0   23
1   2009    0   33
1   2010    1   56
1   2011    0   14
1   2012    0   23
2   2008    0   45
2   2009    0   38
2   2010    0   16
2   2011    1   7
2   2012    0   26
```

the final dataframe is

```
id  year    list    value
1   2009    0   33
1   2011    0   14
2   2010    0   16
2   2012    0   26
```

what the code in R to process this data?Thank you in advance!

Comment: Revise your question, I don't fully understand what you are asking for.

Comment: sorry for my bad question description.what i want to get is for any oberservation which list=1, mark this oberservation's id and year, and return this id's ahead year and follow year's oberservation.like the 3rd oberservation's list equal 1,so only reserve 2cd and 4th obersevation and drop others.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will have at most one `list=1` per ID, you can use `dplyr` `filter()` call. For example

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(year %in% (year[list==1] + c(-1,1)))
#      id  year  list value
# <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1  2009     0    33
# 2     1  2011     0    14
# 3     2  2010     0    16
# 4     2  2012     0    26
```

with the sample input

```
dd<-read.table(text="id  year    list    value
1   2008    0   23
1   2009    0   33
1   2010    1   56
1   2011    0   14
1   2012    0   23
2   2008    0   45
2   2009    0   38
2   2010    0   16
2   2011    1   7
2   2012    0   26", header=T)
```

If you had more than one per ID, then this should work

```
dd %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(year %in% sapply(year[list==1], `+`, c(-1,1)))
```

Comment: yes,every id only have one list=1.Very thanks, but i can not understand  “dd” “%>%” …… it hard for a rookie ,is there any simple code to get the same result

Comment: I tried to make it as simple as I could. Maybe checkout more info on the [dplyr package](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: Thanks！I get it.Thank you for your help.